# how to resolve classification problem for categorial data?

Tags: python, classification

I want to **classify** a set of data that have **categorial features**(yes/no). do you have any **ideas** that can help me to start my work.
i have tried LDA algorithm but it doesn't work for my case, because i am looking for a **classification** rather than **clustering**.
thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details or some samples about this problem.

If it is a problem to classify boys and girls, you can use `if`, while if it is a problem to classify handwriting numbers like [MNIST](https://deepai.org/dataset/mnist), you may use some machine-learning methods such as [MLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayer_perceptron) or [CNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network).